# How to move a function to a separate assembly from the interface [Error]

Tags: c#

I am currently working on a file copying facility that allows me to select a source and a destination for the folders to be copied from and to. A progress bar is displayed after the user clicks on Copy.

The only issue is that All of my functions reside in one file which is form1.cs (as follows)

```
namespace CopyFacility
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        BackgroundWorker background = new BackgroundWorker();
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowser = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        OpenFileDialog openFile = new OpenFileDialog();


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            background.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            background.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            background.DoWork += Background_DoWork;
            background.RunWorkerCompleted += Background_RunWorkerCompleted;
            background.ProgressChanged += Background_ProgressChanged;

        }

        string inputFile = null;
        string outputFile = null;


        private void CopyFile(string source, string destination, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            FileStream fsOut = new FileStream(destination, FileMode.Create);
            FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(source, FileMode.Open);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1048756];
            int readBytes;
            while((readBytes = fsIn.Read(buffer,0,buffer.Length)) > 0)
            {
                if(background.CancellationPending)
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    background.ReportProgress(0);
                    fsIn.Close();
                    fsOut.Close();
                    return;
                }
                else
                {
                    fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                    background.ReportProgress((int) (fsIn.Position * 100 / fsIn.Length));
                }


                fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
                background.ReportProgress((int)(fsIn.Position * 100 / fsIn.Length));
            }

            fsIn.Close();
            fsOut.Close();

        }

        private void Background_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            fileProgressBar.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        private void Background_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if(e.Cancelled)
            {
                fileProgressBar.Visible = true;
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
                lblMessage.Text = "The process has been cancelled";
            }
            else
            {
                fileProgressBar.Visible = true;
                lblMessage.Visible = true;
                lblMessage.Text = "The process has been completed";
            }
        }

        private void Background_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            CopyFile(inputFile, outputFile + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(inputFile),e);

        }


        private void btnCancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            background.CancelAsync();
        }

        private void btnCopy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(background.IsBusy)
            {
                lblProgress.Visible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                fileProgressBar.Visible = true;
                background.RunWorkerAsync();
            }
        }

        private void btnSource_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK )
            {
                inputFile = openFile.FileName;
                btnSource.Text = inputFile;
            }
        }

        private void btnDestination_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (folderBrowser.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                outputFile = folderBrowser.SelectedPath;
                btnDestination.Text = outputFile + @"\" + Path.GetFileName(inputFile);
            }
        }


    }
}
```

I was wondering how I could go about putting the function "CopyFile" into it's own class that can be called whenever the button is clicked?

When I try creating a new class method and inserting the functions related to the copying function into a new class "CopyFunction.cs" , I get a following error from the code "InitializingComponent();" as follows

```
public CopyPresenter(BackgroundWorker background, FolderBrowserDialog folderBrwoser, OpenFileDialog openFile)
        {

            InitializeComponent();

            background.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
            background.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            background.DoWork += Background_DoWork;
            background.RunWorkerCompleted += Background_RunWorkerCompleted;
            background.ProgressChanged += Background_ProgressChanged;
        }
```

The error says that the "InitializeComponent" doesn't exist in the current context.

Comment: `InitializeComponent()` tells the form to display itself. Your class doesn't need that.

Comment: And I'm not sure you're going about this right. Having all the code in the form isn't necessarily a bad thing, especially when - as here - the code is coupled to the form, because it is reporting back progress. If you didn't need to do that, you would just call [`File.Copy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: Yes, you could have a separate class to which you pass `inputFile` and `outputFile` and the background worker from your form, but what's that really going to achieve? I see you've tagged the question as `computer-science`, so from that perspective - classes should be responsible for one thing. Your form does one thing - copies a file and reports on progress. So it is reasonable for the code which copies the file and reports on progress to be within one class - the form.

Comment: The computer-science tag was accidental, but yes you are correct, I guess I don't need to seperate them that much especially with such a simple software. Thank you for the advice